# ¿Cómo agrupar mis consultas en Mysql/Dql?

Tags: mysql, dql

Trato de agrupar mis consultas de modo que me vote todos los registros realizador por una sola persona.

**De momento lo tengo así:**

```
   public function reportecasa()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
            SELECT e , em, c , cc , ca
            From App:EmpCli e
            JOIN e.idcliente c 
            JOIN e.idempleado em
            JOIN c.clienCas cc
            JOIN cc.idcasa ca
            WHERE c.id = e.idcliente and e.idempleado = em.id and c.id=cc.idcliente and cc.idcasa = ca.id
        ')->getResult();
    }
```

**En el Twig lo tengo asi:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pero al momento de mostrarlo pegado a otro, sale así:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es la estructura de tu base de datos? ¿Qué te gustaría obtener?

Comment: En lugar de tenerlo como en la imagen quisiera tener todo, lo que hizo dicho vendedor, sin que se repita cada rato su nombre.